# Apache: Except a path from RewriteRule

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, apache

I'm trying to except from being redirected to `/portal/` if you access to `/sitemapHT/` but it seems that this process `^(/$|!sitemapHT)` is wrong, since it still redirecting me to /portal/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/opt/tomcat-5.5.30/webapps/portal"
        ServerName hoteles
        ServerAlias hoteles

        JkUnMount       /images/*.gif           w1
        JkUnMount       /images/*.png           w1
        JkUnMount       /images/*.jpg           w1
        JkUnMount       /js/*.js                w1
        JkUnMount       /styles/*.css           w1


        JkMount         /portal                 w1
        JkMount         /portal/*               w1


        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
        RewriteRule .* - [F]
        Options +FollowSymlinks

        RewriteRule   ^(/$|!sitemapHT)  /portal/  [R]
        RewriteRule ^/(?!portal)(.*) /portal/ficha.action/$1 [PT]

</VirtualHost>
```

Could you suggest me a proper correction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^/(sitemapHT/|portal/)
RewriteRule ^(.*) /portal/ [R,L]
```

This will redirect (302 code) ALL incoming requests to `/portal/` EXCEPT `/sitemapHT/` or when requesting `/portal/` directly.

---

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteCond $1 !^/(sitemapHT/|portal/)
RewriteRule ^(.*) /portal/ [R,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(sitemapHT/|portal/)
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /portal/ficha.action/$1 [PT]
```

Use the above rules instead of your last 2 lines:

```
RewriteRule ^(/$|!sitemapHT) /portal/ [R]
RewriteRule ^/(?!portal)(.*) /portal/ficha.action/$1 [PT]
```

Comment: what if we have 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)' already? Does it affects it?

Comment: our current rewrite, redirects everything to /portal/, which is correct, but I need to except /sitemapHT/ from this redirect, which would be the usage of the rules you wrote?

Comment: Well this rule is to block unwanted request methods regardless of the actual URL ([HTTP Method Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)). Redirect uses GET or POST method. For general purpose websites GET,POST and HEAD are absolutely enough. But yes -- if someone will attempt to access your site using TRACE or TRACK methods he will see error screen instead of redirect. And I think it is a correct behaviour.

Comment: Yes, my rule redirects EVERYTHING EXCEPT `/sitemapHT/` and `/portal/` (as there is no point of rewriting `/portal/` to the exactly same URL creating rewrite loop, right?)

Comment: What if I have to keep all this rules:

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
        RewriteRule .* - [F]
        Options +FollowSymlinks

        RewriteRule   ^/$  /portal/  [R]
        RewriteRule ^/(?!portal)(.*) /portal/ficha.action/$1 [PT]` Which should I replace for your rules?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/(?!portal)(.*) /portal/ficha.action/$1 [PT]` which is my original rule, is not working with your modification, since the application generates URLs like: `/hotel-nahuel-huapi_7196099490048368` Any suggestions?

Comment: @BoDiE2003 Try removing leading slash `/` from pattern: `^(?!portal)(.*)`

Comment: Thank you for your help, there were changes in the application and now they made some changes but I still cannot make it work, if you can take a look to this post, Ill be grateful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850530/apache-problems-with-redirects