# Apache: Problems with redirects

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the next rules, and I should be able to access to this URLs without any problem:

`domain.com/robots.txt` - should redirect me to -> `domain.com/sitemapHT/robots.txt`
now robots.txt has an index of xmls files, where does the sitemaps for different sections of the site write its sitemap. For example: `domain.com/sitemapHT/sitemap_anuciantes.xml`

With the current rules (below) When I try to access to any of the /robots.txt or sitemapHT urls, it sends me to domain.com/

The rules also are redirecting from old `/portal/index.action` url we have, to a new just `/`

Could you help me to fix the rules to access properly to the previous urls?

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin administracion.linux@yellargentina.com
        DocumentRoot "/opt/tomcat-5.5.30/webapps/portal"
        ServerName hoteles.t1.yellargentina.com
        ServerAlias hoteles.t1.yellargentina.com
        CustomLog /tmp/hoteles-access_log combined
        ErrorLog /tmp/hoteles-error_log
        RewriteLog /tmp/hoteles-rewrite_log
        RewriteLogLevel 3

        JkUnMount       /images/*.gif           w1
        JkUnMount       /images/*.png           w1
        JkUnMount       /images/*.jpg           w1
        JkUnMount       /js/*.js                w1
        JkUnMount       /styles/*.css           w1


        JkMount         /portal                 w1
        JkMount         /portal/*               w1


        RewriteEngine on

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
        RewriteRule .* - [F]
        Options +FollowSymlinks


        ##
        # Originales
        ##

        ##
        RewriteRule ^/robots.txt /sitemapHT/robots.txt [R=301]
        RewriteCond $1 !^/(sitemapHT/|portal/)
        ##

        #RewriteRule ^/$ /portal/ [R]
        #RewriteRule ^/(?!portal)(.*) /portal/ficha.action/$1 [PT]

        RewriteRule ^/$ /portal/index.action [PT]
        RewriteRule ^/portal/index.action / [R]
        RewriteRule ^/(?!portal)(.*) /portal/ficha.action/$1 [PT]
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you!

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 2 lines together make no much sense:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^/(sitemapHT/|portal/)
RewriteRule ^/robots.txt /sitemapHT/robots.txt [R=301]
```

This single line will do the job of rewriting (if you want redirect add `R=301,` next to `L`) `domain.com/robots.txt` into `domain.com/sitemapHT/robots.txt`:

```
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /sitemapHT/robots.txt [L]
```

**P.S.** You rewrite log (the last code block in question body) is unreadable. Please format it properly.

**P.P.S.** If you have other rules in your .htaccess, they may affect this rewrite rule. It is better if you provide whole .htaccess if this one will not work.

---

**UPDATE:**

1. No need for this line: `RewriteCond $1 !^/(sitemapHT/|portal/)`, especially if it *after* rewrite rule.

2. What these 2 lines do?

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /portal/index.action [PT]
RewriteRule ^/portal/index.action / [R]
```

As for me -- they do opposite jobs. But if it works then I will not touch it.

Try these rewrite rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^/robots.txt /sitemapHT/robots.txt [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s/portal/index.action\sHTTP/.+
RewriteRule ^/portal/index.action$ / [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/$ /portal/index.action [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^/(?!portal|sitemapHT)(.*) /portal/ficha.action/$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Man, I have cleaned the topic with lattest virtualdirectory and right RewriteLog output. The output is when I try to access /robots.txt, that should be rewritten to /sitemapHT/robots.txt

Comment: No matter which URL I'm trying, its sending me to Tomcat welcome page.

Comment: Rules `RewriteRule ^/$ /portal/index.action [PT]
RewriteRule ^/portal/index.action / [R]` are to redirect the browsing to the application homepage, and later hide the `/portal/index.action` to show the clean url.

Comment: @BoDiE2003 Maybe it is Tomcat issue? In any case -- please enable rewrite debugging, clear rewrite log, do a request for 1 (only one, as simple as possible) problematic URL and provide rewrite log (update your question).

Comment: I've updated my initial topic with the info of rewrite logs for 2 test cases.

Comment: our application root / homepage is `/portal/index.action` but  we want the aplication to point there and then hide that url to be just `domain.com` without `/portal/index.action` behind.

Comment: @BoDiE2003 1) Can you please set `RewriteLogLevel` to **9** instead of 3 and provide rewrite log again (my apologies, but current level does not provide enough info for me to understand what is going on) and 2) I have added `L` flag to some of the rules -- can you do the same.

Comment: I see that `/robots.txt` gets redirected to `/sitemapHT/robots.txt` .. but the `#do not rewrite existing files` rule does not work (does `/sitemapHT/robots.txt` file really exist?) and request gets rewritten to `/portal/ficha.action/sitemapHT/robots.txt`, which is not a correct URL as I understand. Can you please provide me the real path to the robots.txt (how it should be handled)?

Comment: @BoDiE2003 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1962/discussion-between-lazyone-and-bodie2003)